# How to loop through the command for number of files in directory using bash?

Tags: python, bash, syntax, operating-system

Here iam using a bash script which runs like this

```
for d in os.listdir($folder_name); do
        echo "Running the scanner :"
        python bd.py $folder_name/$d
done
```

Here iam downloading some files to my directory name `folder_name` then i want to run the script taking arguments as each and every file name.I tried to use this logic but it failed giving me this error.

```
./test: line 29: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./test: line 29: `for d in os.listdir($folder_name); do'
```

Is there any way to repeat the loop taking each file as argument and passing it to the python file.

Comment: I don't see any Bash script, that looks like Python.

Comment: Well, now that you have deleted `import os`... you still have `os.listdir`, which looks like Python.

Comment: Still looks weird for me

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it.

Comment: SaiKiran: Refer @heemayl's logic below, that is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, you want to iterate over the files in a directory and run some `python` script taking each filename as argument; if so, just globbing to get the filenames would do:

```
for f in /directory/*; do python bd.py "$f"; done
```

Replace `/directory/` with the actual directory name.

`os.listdir()` is a function from `os` module in `python` that returns a list containing the contents of a directory as strings, the same thing you can achieve with simple shell globbing in any shell.